# Какая система присвоения имен файлам и создания структуры в Python проекте?

Tags: python

Изучаю Python и задание написать клиент и сервер для приема метрик.
Для закрепления и повторения материала решил делать задание в git репозитории с коммитами.

```
12.01.2018  23:31                32 .gitignore
13.01.2018  11:59    <DIR>          .idea
13.01.2018  11:56    <DIR>          client
12.01.2018  22:55    <DIR>          env
12.01.2018  22:42                 0 README.md
12.01.2018  22:29                 0 requirements.txt
12.01.2018  22:46    <DIR>          server
```

В .gitignore добавил .idea и env/

Интересует файловая структура в Python проекте.
Как разбивать код по файлам и есть ли какие то стандартные имена файлов?
Типа файл index у сайта.

Comment: У вас вопрос про питон или про гит?

Comment: хороший вопрос, поправил себя. вопрос на стыке

Comment: Погуляйте по гитхабу, посмотрите на активные проекты на питоне. А лучше сейчас не заморачивайтесь по этому поводу.

Comment: думал оформить правильно даже учебный проект, что бы хоть какое то прортфолио было) пока учу вечерами и в выходные

Comment: Питон это язык общего назначения. Структура проекта существенно *не ограничена*, разные проекты могут иметь разную структуру (CLI, GUI, web-app, lib). Если вы много однотипных проектов создаёте, то начальную структуру можно, к примеру, используя cookiecutter создать (но совершенно необязательно подобные инструменты использовать). Конкретные библиотеки для создания web-приложений, могут иметь свои соглашения о структуре директорий, имён файлов иметь (и сопутствующие инструменты -- см. документацию для выбранной web-framework).

Comment: Чаще всего (но не обязательно) питон-проект имеет файл `setup.py`, который позволяет собрать проект виде какого-нибудь пакета (whl, например, который можно будет загрузить на PyPI), ну а вся остальная структура в целом получается как следствие использования `setup.py` сама по себе

Comment: И, кстати, из-за того же самого PyPI в питон-проектах вместо Markdown предпочтительнее использовать reStructuredText (`README.rst`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-cookicutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) установите и посмотрите проанализируйте. По сути готовы шаблон для создания проекта на джанге/питоне. В частности посмотрите application users.

надеюсь, что поможет